# Repeat this javascript every 1 seconds

Tags: javascript, repeat

I want to repeat this script every second.

```js
<script>
var tdList = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i< tdList.length; i++){ 
  if(parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())>= 0 && parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())< 5 && tdList[i].getAttribute('id') == "X")
  tdList[i].innerHTML = '<img title="test" src="http://i.imgur.com/bgwZcHq.png">'
}
</script>
```

I have another javascript which repeats itself every second but i dont know how to add function from this script to the first one.

```js
<script>
window.setInterval(function() {  
    httpGetAsync('1.php', function(text) {  
        if (document.getElementById("1").innerHTML >= 5000) { 
document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/F0zuFZV.png">'
        } 

    });  
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Why not wrap the first in a name, like function DoWhatever() { your code }, and then call it in the second?

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id in the document: `tdList[i].getAttribute('id') == "X"` that's invalid html. Why not use a user defined attribute for that like `data-id="x"`?

Comment: Dont know how to do. Im not a coder. The code is fine i just need to repeat it every 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

The piece you're looking for is the `window.setInterval(..., 1000);` call. The first parameter to `window.setInterval(` is the function you wish to call. (The second parameter is the number of milliseconds between each time the function is called.) If you defined a function with `function myFuncName() { ... }` then you could pass in the function by name like this: `window.setInterval(myFuncName, 1000);` but in your second example you defined the function inline.

Wrap your first example in a function (or define it inline like your second example) and pass it into window.setInterval to call it each second.